# How is .unwrap() in Option a const function if it's output depends on the instance itself?

Tags: rust

Was just looking around the rust stdlib and noticed that the unwrap associated function for Option is labelled as a const function, which should mean that it's value can be known at compile time... right? But the value of the Option is what dictates that though.

Comment: Please note, that `unwrap` is currently const unstable, which means you need the `const_option` feature gate.

Comment: The requirement for a const function isn't that it has always the same output, but rather that it's output only depends on it's input arguments. There can't be any dependence on external state, nor any side effects, i.e. the function must be _pure_ in order to be constant. `Option::unwrap()` is a pure function, so with constant input in can be evaluated to constant output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` functions mean they *can* be compile-time evaluated *if* they're being evaluated in const context. But they can still be called at run-time if they're being used outside a const context. Essentially, this is just saying "If you have an `Option` with a compile-time known value, and the value can be manipulated at compile-time too, [and all the stars align for const context](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html) you can extract the contents at compile-time too."

Answer (score 3):

No. A constant, like `const C: Type = value;` is what you think about. A `const fn` is a function that can be evaluated in *const contexts*. That means that, for instance, you can call `unwrap()` in the initializer of a const:

```rust
const V: i32 = Some(1).unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4c555a4d445f018f8b80362213426d2). Note that `const` `unwrap()` is still unstable.

If `unwrap()` wouldn't `const fn`, that would cause an error:

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `not_const_unwrap` in constants
 --> src/lib.rs:3:16
  |
3 | const V: i32 = not_const_unwrap(Some(1));
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

This is not the only const context: for example, `static` initializers are, too.

See [the RFC that introduced `const fn`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0911-const-fn.html) for details.